# C / C++ Literals

Tags: c++, c

Can someone help me to identify in the standards (C99 and C++03) what happens to the line below?

```
uint16_t a = 5;
```

So, on the left is the typed variable, on the right is the literal, when and how does the literal value get the type of the variable?

Is the above assignment is equivalent to statement below?

```
uint16_t a = (uint16_t)5;  /* C */
uint16_t a = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t>(5);  // C++
```

How about:

```
uint16_t a = 5u;
```

Then if you have something like:

```
uint32_t b = a + 5;
```

Is the statement above equivalent to statement below?

```
uint32_t b = (uint32_t)(a + (uint16_t)(5));  /* C */
uint32_t b = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(a + reinterpret_cast<uint16_t>(5));  // C++
```

Do things change in C11 and C++14?  Also, please assume that the system int is 32 bit.

I have been coding in C for a while, but never really understood it deeply, but it always bothers me, so I would appreciate if someone can help me to sort it out.

Thank you...

(Edited: added assumption that the int is 32 bit)

Comment: Well finally we have a question tagged both C and C++ and it is **indeed** related to both :)

Comment: That would be `static_cast` not `reinterpret_cast` (which is only for conversions involving pointers and references).

Comment: `5` is of type `int` and `5u` is of type `unsigned int`.

Comment: For arithmetic opeartions, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is that first the RHS is evaluated, and then the value is converted for the target type. In particular

```
uint32_t b = a + 5;
```

is equivalent to

```
uint32_t b = (uint32_t)((int)a + 5);
```

If `uint16_t` is a narrow type, narrower than `int`.

All operations in C (and I think also in C++) are at least at an integer rank of `int`.

Comment: Is `uint32_t a = 1.8 + 0.3;` also a good example? (Since floating point numbers get *truncated* when converting to an integer type, the result `2` shows that the values get added *before* being converted.)

Comment: "rank of int". Bytes are what truly matters imo.

Comment: @Jongware, sure, good example. First the expression on right is evaluated as `double`, and then converted to `uint32_t`